# Не получается вывести рандомные картинки в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть рабочий код (проверял на чистом php), все работает, выводятся картинки рандомные с директории, но пробую вывести в шаблоне wordpress - ничего не выводит. Не могли бы подсказать? Вот код

```
$root = '';
$path = 'images/';
function getImagesFromDir($path) {
    $images = array();
    if ( $img_dir = @opendir($path) ) {
        while ( false !== ($img_file = readdir($img_dir)) ) {
            // checks for gif, jpg, png
            if ( preg_match("/(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$/", $img_file) ) {
                $images[] = $img_file;
            }
        }
        closedir($img_dir);
    }
    return $images;
}

function getRandomFromArray($ar) {
    mt_srand( (double)microtime() * 1000000 ); // php 4.2+ not needed
    $num = array_rand($ar);
    return $ar[$num];
}

// Obtain list of images from directory 
$imgList = getImagesFromDir($root . $path);

$img = getRandomFromArray($imgList);
```

Comment: `$path = '/images/';` - если скрипт НЕ в корне сайта, указывай путь к папке относительно корня сайта

Comment: я так пробовал - не помогает. Также пробовал полный путь писать - http://site.com/ .... Я полагаю в ROOT надо что-то писать. ...Пробовал в ROOT это $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо заменить

```
$imgList = getImagesFromDir($root . $path);
```

на

```
$imgList = getImagesFromDir($root . '/' . $path)
```

Comment: Сделал. Файл создался. Вот мой путь $path = 'wp-content/themes/generic/images/'; 

Но картинка при этом не выводится . У меня ничего не инклюдится. Все пишу в файле header.php и функцию и ее вызов

Comment: Не понимаю, файл же создается...

Comment: Да, data.txt создается в папке images.
Попробовал var_dump($img_file); - Забавно, но ничего не выводит, вообще пусто.... Блин как так . Я использую тему вордпресс generic

Comment: Добавил. Вот что вывело

string(33) "wp-content/themes/generic/images/" string(50) "Z:/home/site1/wwwwp-content/themes/generic/images/"

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста, вот мой код

`var_dump($path);
function getImagesFromDir($path) {
    $images = array();
 var_dump($path);
    if ( $img_dir = @opendir($path) ) {
  var_dump($path);
        while ( false !== ($img_file = readdir($img_dir)) ) {
   var_dump($img_file);
            // checks for gif, jpg, png
            if ( preg_match("/(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$/", $img_file) ) {
                $images[] = $img_file;
            }
        }
  
  
        closedir($img_dir);
  
    }
    return $images;
}`

Comment: Добавил как вы сказали

`$imgList = getImagesFromDir($root . '/' . $path);`

Вот резултат что вывело

string(33) "wp-content/themes/generic/images/" string(51) "Z:/home/site1/www/wp-content/themes/generic/images/" string(51) "Z:/home/site1/www/wp-content/themes/generic/images/" string(1) "." string(2) ".." string(17) "Chrysanthemum.jpg" string(8) "data.txt" string(10) "Desert.jpg" string(9) "fb-32.png" string(8) "find.png" string(14) "Hydrangeas.jpg" string(13) "Jellyfish.jpg"

Comment: @user3654202 Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению диалога на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев. Если у вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно, сославшись на этот для предоставления контекста.

Comment: Все верно var_dump можете убрать с кода- у вас уже все работает..судя по логу......Эти комметарии можно удалить я так полагаю..

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky извините

Comment: @Lesyuk Alexey честно говоря картинки так и не отображаются ... Может быть что-то блокирует отображение картинок?

Comment: @Lesyuk Alexey Может это нагло, но если у вас вордпресс стоит, может быть вы сможете посмотреть на этой теме generic? Просто странно, все же должно отображать

Comment: Вы же при включенном  var_dump сами написали что картинки перечисляются. Пишите в Skype: MiddleSky3 в нерабочее время помогу..

Comment: Сами изображения НЕ выводятся, а названия да - показываются. Я писал в скайп